# Springboot could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Currently I am getting a problem with fetching mysql data for my springboot project:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

**TestEntity.java**

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String p1;
    private String p2;
    private String p3;

    public TestEntity() {
    }

    public TestEntity(int id, String p1, String p2, String p3){
        this.id = id;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.p3 = p3;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public void setP1(String p1) {
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    public String getP2() {
        return p2;
    }

    public void setP2(String p2) {
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public String getP3() {
        return p3;
    }

    public void setP3(String p3) {
        this.p3 = p3;
    }



}
```

**TestService.java**

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;

    public ArrayList<TestEntity> getAllTestEntities(){
       ArrayList<TestEntity> list = new ArrayList();
       testRepository.findAll().forEach(list::add);
       return list;
    }

    public Optional getTestEntity(int id){
       return testRepository.findById(id);
    }
    public void addTestEntity(TestEntity t){
        testRepository.save(t);
    }
    public void removeTestEntity(int index){

        testRepository.deleteById(index);

    }

}
```

**TestRepository.java**

```
@Repository("mysql")
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestEntity,Integer> {



}
```

**TestController.java**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping("/test/AllUnits")
    public ArrayList<TestEntity> getAllTestUnits(){
        return testService.getAllTestEntities();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test/{id}")
    public Optional getAllTestUnit(@PathVariable int id){
        return testService.getTestEntity(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value = "/test" )
    public void addTestUnit(@RequestBody TestEntity t){
        testService.addTestEntity(t);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE,value = "/test/{id}" )
    public void deleteTestUnit(@RequestBody Integer id){
        testService.removeTestEntity(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test/welcome")
    public String welcome(){

        return "welcome to springboot";

    }


}
```

**Edit**: **application.properties**

```
cloud.aws.region.auto=true
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-2

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://alyxdev.czcdgqfkwsnr.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/CryptoCurrency
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******
```

I am able to get the /test/welcome mapping working so I believe my implementation of the service and controller is correct. So I am wondering if I made a mistake for accessing my database in my repository or should I use a JpaRepository instead of a CrudRepository and use an explicit query?

**Edit Stack Trace**: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'CryptoCurrency.test_entity' doesn't exist

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Here are some clue. If there's other config files and check it. If you changed attributes while columns are not changed in database.

Comment: added stack trace to the edit.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the repository, then using raw types?

Comment: Does the table `CryptoCurrency.test_entity` really exists? Consider specifying the table name using `@Table` annotation in your Entity class. Also, Please post the `application.properties` file as well.

Comment: I am not sure how to specify the table in springboot. It seems to thing test_entity is the table which was the model class for this application. The actual table name is Test_table which holds three fields and a id key.

Comment: So, `@Table(name="Test_table")` annotation along with your `@Entity` annotation should work, I guess.

Comment: based on `CryptoCurrency.test_entity`, does your schema `CryptoCurrency` has table `test_entity`?

Answer (score 2):

In you Entity class i.e. TestEntity.java, you need to specify which table that your referring to

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_something")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
```

And use of CrudRepository would be fine for excessing the database.
The application.properties file looks good to me.

Comment: So i added the '@Table("Test_table")' annotation however I still get the same problem. 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'CryptoCurrency.test_table' doesn't exist'

Comment: does the value of attribute of table i.e. test_table match the database table... it is clearly indicating that the connection pool is not able to connect.
The table name should match from entity to database.

Comment: for me, i forgot to change the table name, so it refers to wrong table. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem I was having apparently by renaming the table to all lowercase characters (`test_table`) in SQL and then using that table instead of `Test_table` Springboot was able to find that table and link map it to my entity class. I have no idea why it works this way. Maybe something to do with the Netbeans IDE I am using perhaps?

Comment: It's because MySQL table names are case-sensitive on *nix, and Amazon instance you are using is *nix-based. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

If annotate your entity class with @Table(name = "EmplyeeSalary") then JPA generates employee_salary as the table name. According to the naming convention at every uppercase found in the name, a new word will be generated with all lower case and will be separated from previous using _.

If you annotate your entity class like @Table(name = "AbcDefGhi") then JPA will look for abc_def_ghi table.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to a column was not added in table But in my entity class I am expecting that